# Replace default icon in WP8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Create a WP8.1 app.

On my device/emulator my app is using the default icon (as shown below).

[image]

How do I replace that icon with my own please?

Comment: Have you looked into manifest file? Some information also at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662929(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: @Romasz Sorry, I missed your comment yesterday.  Yes I did look at that but it was not specific enough.  In the end I created every size and put a 'tag' in each image to find out what goes where. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Package Manifest -> Visual Assets(tab). Here you can change the logo.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx

You can download the Visual Assets Templates from [here](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/design/assets). You can use these as a starting point to create your own.

Comment: Hi, ta for replying. Yes I have looked there but I do not know which icon is for which. I do not find it that clear

Comment: Read more at the link. But these are the ones used for Logo:
Square 71x71 Logo, 
Square 150x150 Logo,
Wide 310x150 Logo,
Square 44x44 Logo

These are the different tile sizes you can choose one your phone. Just upload one scaled logo for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was 62x62 pixels